# Create a sliding div on click

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a div that float on the right side of the screen.
When you click on it, it slides and you can see the content.
I tried to look on the web for this but I didn't know the keywords.
How can I create this effect?

[image]

Comment: You can do it in CSS as well as javascript.

Comment: Found this link. http://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/KFmLv/

Comment: not hard to find lots of plugins and tutorials for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, will it work for you?

https://jsfiddle.net/gwxhz3pe/6/

```
var width;

$('#content').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('open')){
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        width = "10px";
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('open');
        width = "300px";
    }
    $(this).animate({
        width: width
      }, 200, function() {
      });

});
```

Comment: Yes this is what I have been looking for, is there a way to close the div again on click?

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/gwxhz3pe/6/